# Software update Error & how to install Plug-ins in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install plug-ins in my eclipse Indigo via Help-Install New Software but it showing following error window as "***Cannot complete the request.This Installation had not been configured properly for software update. see the error log***". please guide me how to install new plug-ins in eclipse and how to add EMC in menu bar of eclipse![image showing error while installing new software in eclipse][1]

thanks in advance.

Nakul

Comment: I am having the same error on windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error if you are trying to update an Eclipse/RCP application running from within Eclipse (Run or Debug).

If this is the case, have a look in the launch configuration. On the "Configuration" tab, you can find a setting "Support software installation in the launched application". Check this :-)

Comment: thank you for help Tonny. I directly installed new version of Eclipse for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Mac?
This bug thread on eclipse discussed a similar issue
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305758

It was to do with the unarchiver app on Mac.